# Which middot character is this?

Tags: php, special-characters

`$string = 'Single · Female'`

I copied it from facebook.
In `html source` its just that dot, how did they type it?
While `echo`ing in `php` its A with circumflex (Â) concatenated with that same dot.

How can i explode this string with that dot?

Comment: its an ascii char probably in the UTF-8 size find the character code in char map and use that to match/split on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an [interpunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct). It can be used through the HTML entities `&#183;` or `&middot;` and in PHP with the unicode value `U+00B7`.

If you want to echo the unicode character without HTML entities, you can set the character encoding to UTF-8. Splitting is done through `explode("·", $textToSplit)` given that your PHP file is using UTF-8 as character encoding.

Comment: it doesn't explode with that separator

Comment: use htmlencode on your input string that'll replace it with the &middot; html then just explode("&middot;",$texttosplit)

Comment: Perhaps the character encoding of your file is affecting the functionality. You can also try `explode("·", $textToSplit)` or changing the character encoding of your PHP file to UTF-8.

Comment: `\u00B7` is not a supported escape sequence in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

It is U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT, a character used for many purposes, e.g. as a separator between links, alternatives, or other items.

If your code displays it as Â·, then the reason is that the UTF-8 encoded form of U+00B7, namely 0xC2 0xB7, is being misinterpreted as being ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 encoded. You should fix this basic problem (instead of trying to deal with some of its symptoms). See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Regarding the question “how did they type it?”, we cannot really know, and we need not know. There are zillions of ways to type characters, and anyone can invent a few more. (On my keyboard, I use AltGr Shift X. If I needed to type “·” on a Windows computer with vanilla settings, I would use Alt 0183.)